# Error when creating a process in C# and using relative path with folders

Tags: c#, jar, process, console, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a program in C# that has to call an external process (a jar file in this case).
If I put the jar and all the files that it uses in the same folder of my exe the call succeed, but if I place all these files in a folder (even on the same level of the exe) the arguments that I pass the the jar seem to be off.

This is a small program I used for testing:

```
private static async Task Main()
{
    // Build the process arguments
    string arguments = $"-jar {JarPath}";

    // Create the process 
    Process process = CreateProcess(ExePath, arguments, "1", "file.json", "file");
    Console.WriteLine($"Process arguments: {process.StartInfo.Arguments}");

    // Then wait for it to complete (custom made extension method)
    await process.WaitForExitAsync();

    // Print process generated output
    string standardOutput = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(standardOutput);

    Console.Write("Press 'ENTER' to exit: ");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static Process CreateProcess(string exePath, params string[] arguments)
{
    string args = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Length; i++)
        args += $"{arguments[i]} ";

    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        FileName = exePath,
        Arguments = args.TrimEnd(),
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };

    Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    return process;
}
```

In the code above `ExePath` is the path of java.exe and `JarPath` is the path to the jar file that I have to execute.
If it is something like "jarFileName.jar" the code works fine and I have a certain standard output, but if it's something like "folder\jarFileName.jar" the output changes from the previous case and the jar actually doesn't work as intended.

Any ideas? I'm not that familiar with cdm arguments, maybe is something related to that

Comment: Any error messages you could add?

Comment: I assume your program is missing the necessary rights to navigate folders. Try running visual studio as administrator

Comment: Actually the only thing that the jar says when I get the error is "Invalid TPP type" (that is the argument "file.json" in the example), while I get a different output if I place the jar directly in the same folder of my exe and the jar actually executes and produce the effects that I expect

Comment: I've just tried to run vs as administrator but nothing changed. From my understanding maybe it's something related to the slashes that I added in the path, even if it seems strange